# How to lock a user using ansible?

Tags: ansible

Given a username, if that user exists, lock it, otherwise keep it missing.

The most likely module is `ansible.builtin.user`. There passing `password: "*"` and `shell: "/usr/sbin/nologin"` mostly achieves the lock behavior, but it also creates the user. The `state` property only has possible values `present` and `absent`, neither of which describes the desired behavior.

One can obtain a fact on the user presence using `ansible.builtin.getent` and then conditionally use `ansible.builtin.user`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *... mostly achieves the lock behavior, but it also creates the user. The `state` property only has possible values `present` and `absent` ...*

Right, that would be the best approach and expected behavior.

> *One can obtain a fact on the user presence using `ansible.builtin.getent` and then conditionally use `ansible.builtin.user`.*

And also right, this would be too the recommended approach.

In other words, currently there is no possibility to configure such within one single task and if not using `shell` module, custom scripts or custom modules.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible, only disable existing users?](https://serverfault.com/a/1035610/448950)